# Python Pandas Join: If One Column Does Not Work, Try Others

Tags: python, pandas, merge

Given the following data frames:

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Last':['Smith','Jones','Johnson'], 'First': ['Tom', 'Jim', 'Neil'], 'DOB':['1/1/2010', '3/1/2012', '4/3/2011'], 'ID': [1,2,3]})
df1


     DOB      First  ID Last
0   1/1/2010    Tom  1  Smith
1   3/1/2012    Jim  2  Jones
2   4/3/2011    Neil 3  Johnson

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Last':['S','J','Johnson'], 'First': ['T', 'J', 'Neil'], 'DOB':['1/1/2010', '3/1/2012', '4/3/2011'],'ID': [1,2,5]})
df2

     DOB    First   ID  Last
0   1/1/2010    T   1   S
1   3/1/2012    J   2   J
2   4/3/2011    Neil5   Johnson
```

I'd like to join (merge) them in pandas as follows:

1. Try to merge on ID = ID
2. Where matches do not exist (i.e. for Neil Johnson),

a.       Merge on Last, First, DOB = Last, First, DOB

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## merge on ID

```
df3 = pd.merge(df1,df2,on='ID')
```

## merge remaining entries on dob, first and last

```
df4 = pd.merge(df1.drop(df3.index), df2.drop(df3.index), on = ['DOB','First','Last'])
```

## concat both types of merges:

i'll leave this up to you , you have to decide how you're going to match up your columns.

Comment: Thanks! I'm assuming if I want to continue to join on other columns if there were some that did not match in Last, First, DOB, I would continue the pattern above (i.e. df5 = pd.merge(df1.drop(df4.index), df3.drop(df4.index), on = [next column(s) to use for joining])? What if next, I wanted to match on ID in df1 and a new column (not shown above) called "ID2" in df2?

Comment: I finally sat down and figured out the answer to my follow-up question: df5 = pd.merge (df1.drop (df3.index & df4.index), df2.drop (df3.index & df4.index), left_on = 'ID', right_on = 'ID2')

Comment: One more question: how is pandas matching up the indexes?

Comment: I just tried this with a set of real data and received the following error: ValueError: labels [ 9397  9398  9399 ..., 11764 11765 11766] not contained in axis

Answer (score 1):

regarding the merging :

The merge method accept the following parameters :

- left : keep only the keys from the first dataframe
- right : keep only the keys from the second dataframe
- inner : keep the intersection (that is the default behavior)
- outer : keep the union (all) of the key

So if you want the intersection :

```
merged = pd.merge(df1, df2, on "ID") #id is the key, df1 the first dataframe, df2 the second.
```

that's the equivalent of :

```
merged = pd.merge(df1, df2, on "ID", how="inner")
```

Regarding your point "a" I would strip the first letter out of the "Last" column and then concatenate it with the two others.

```
df1['Last']=df1['Last'].str[:1]
df2['Last']=df2['Last'].str[:1]
```

and

```
df1["key"] = df1["Last"]+df1["First"]+df1["DOB"]
df2["key"] = df2["Last"]+df2["First"]+df2["DOB"]
```

then I would use the merge method :

```
merged = pd.merge(df1, df2, on "key", how="inner")

print(merged)
```